# Unique counter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this table with 15 row.

**[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8isX5QmADnXTKHLKVS7u?p=preview)**

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="item in myObj">
  <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
  <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myObj = [    {
      "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "City": "Berlin",
      "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Around the Horn",
      "City": "London",
      "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
      "Name": "B's Beverages",
      "City": "London",
      "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "City": "Luleå",
      "Country": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
      "City": "Mannheim",
      "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
      "City": "Strasbourg",
      "Country": "France"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bólido Comidas preparadas",
      "City": "Madrid",
      "Country": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bon app'",
      "City": "Marseille",
      "Country": "France"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
      "City": "Bern",
      "Country": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
      "City": "São Paulo",
      "Country": "Brazil"
    }]
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's the output:

[image]

Let's say I delete an object in the array, total row will be `14` and when I add an object into array, it will return to `15`. That was expected.

Now what I want to do is, `WITHOUT` using controller and everything is done in the `VIEW`; after I remove an object and add it back, I want the row will shown as `16` and not `15`. I mean `$index` should be increasing and not decreasing.

I have done it with controller but is it possible to do it with only in the view?

Thanks for your time and any help in advance.

Comment: It might help if you explain why you need to do this. Logic is normally handled in the controller (or maybe a directive).

Comment: Also, your delete functionality isn't in the demo. That's key to this, I think. (You may be able to increment a variable on a button click, for example.)

Comment: Maybe if you just keep the item and disable it via ng-show instead of direct deletion. Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/km29IDfdncq3NviZsHB7?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could "soft-delete" the row. Instead of actually removing it from the array, you can simply mark it as deleted. Then the count will continue to increase as you add items:

```
function softDelete(item) {
  item.deleted = true;
}
```

I don't know why you wouldn't want to use the controller, but this could also be done in the view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in myObj" ng-click="item.deleted = true" ng-hide="item.deleted">
  <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
  <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a plunker demonstrating:

https://plnkr.co/edit/yuAIXn5Pe9YbwxXW2qih?p=preview

Comment: I will try to implement this in my project. Many Thanks.